# Octave - gradients of a circle function do not plot correctly

Tags: octave

## Question

Trying to follow [Gradients, Gradient Plots and Tangent Planes](http://www2.math.umd.edu/~jmr/241/gradients.html#5).

The gradient vectors of (X^2 + Y^2) do not show up correctly in Octave 4.2.0 on Windows. With the code, expected the gradients of a circle diverge from center outwards. However the actual is diagonal.

Please assist to understand what is wrong.

```
syms x y
f1 = x^2 + y^2; 
gradf1 = jacobian(f1,[x,y]);

f1fun  = function_handle(f1);
f1xfun = function_handle(gradf1(1));
f1yfun = function_handle(gradf1(2));

[xx, yy] = meshgrid(-1:.1:1,-1:.1:1);

hold on

contour(xx, yy, f1fun(xx, yy), 10)
quiver(xx, yy, f1xfun(xx, yy), f1yfun(xx, yy), 0.5)
axis equal tight

hold off
```

### Expected

[image]

### Actual

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you perform:

```
f1xfun = function_handle(gradf1(1));
f1yfun = function_handle(gradf1(2));
```

The output is:

```
f1xfun = 
  @(x) 2 * x        % note: single-argument function
f1yfun =
  @(y) 2 * y        % note: single-argument function
```

that is ***AS OPPOSED TO***

```
f1xfun = 
  @(x,y) 2 * x      % two-argument function
f1yfun = 
  @(x,y) 2 * y      % two-argument function
```

which is what you seem to think was happening. (i.e. the resulting functions actually only take a ***single*** input, not both `x` and `y`).

Therefore later on when you call `f1yfun` with two inputs, the second input (i.e. `y`) is simply ***silently discarded***, and you are essentially calculating `2*x` in both axes, hence the diagonal arrows.

---

**tl;dr** Your call to quiver should be:

```
quiver(xx, yy, f1xfun(xx), f1yfun(yy), 0.5);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a bug in your code and the call to quiver should be

```
quiver(xx, yy, f1xfun(xx), f1yfun(yy), 0.5)
```

which then gives (with `colormap("jet")`)

[image: plot from GNU Octave]